# How to distribute NodeJS requests to several servers and merge the results

Tags: node.js

I have a simple NodeJS web app that calls several apis asynchronously and merges the results to return one big result.  Now let's say that I want to optimize this.  How do I do this?

I am new to NoeJS and also the concept of scaling systems.  I have been reading about load balancing, distributed systems, etc...  I think this is the right way to go, but honestly I don't know.

I was thinking of doing something like this -

Set up a system that has several servers, and each has an instance of a NodeJS webapp that makes an api call given a path, and returns the result.

Have a master server that grabs the result from each of these servers, and merge the result and return it to the client.

Is this right way to go?  What technologies do I use?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: You don't need multiple servers to make several API calls at the same time unless you're spending a lot of CPU time processing the result.  The network API calls themselves are truly asynchronous and don't require hardly any of your CPU and node.js excels at doing multiple I/O things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are trying to setup web-crawling or api-crawling, to grab data from 3rd party end point. If that is true, you would have a list of users / IDs or something like that that you pass to the web service you call and grab the data.

First of making a large number of requests very fast and in a stable way is tricky and depends on several factors to be stable and robust.

1. Is the 3rd party API rate limited.
2. Network connection on the client machine making the requests.
3. Error handling for both API and client errors like connection reset etc.
4. Sheer volume of data you are fetching back, like if you are trying to crawl data on millions of users from 3rd party API as fast as possible.

Your instinct is correct that you would have to scale this over several servers or at-least several parallel node processes on machine with lot of resources, however start small, test, and then scale would be my recommendation. Here are a few steps.

1. Use a good robust node http client like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)
2. If you are dealing with huge number of items (username, ids. emails etc) you will need stable way of iterating over them. Put them in a database like **PostgreSQL** or **MySQL**.
3. From here on figure out what's the fastest rate at which your API supports calling. And write stable function to iterate over your 'input' and call the API.
4. Then you have a couple of options. If data you are collecting is separate for each request you make. You can save it back in the database for each input. If you literally want to **merge** the data from multiple API calls, you can use a key-value storage like **Redis**. You can give an ID to each call and create a combination key for **input+request_id** format, then when all requests are done, you can merge them.
5. When you a small scale model in place you can now add a good job manager like [Kue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kue) or [Bull](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bull) to the mix, and split the set of inputs in database from point (2) over several jobs that can be run in parallel.
6. Once you have a stable job-manager for that can repeat this node process for a **range of inputs** , now you are at a point where you can scale.
7. Deploy this same code on multiple servers that all talk to same Database and Redis. Install the Node process to run using a process manager like [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/).
8. Finally the way setup works is, each copy of same node program fetches a different set of inputs (usernames/IDs etc) form the source database, and writes the results back to the database or Redis depending on how you want to handle the output.
9. Optional post processing on redis to fetch the key value pairs and merge the responses grouped by input.

Some important things you have to be hyper aware of when coding this issues are:

1. **Memory Management:** Use design patterns/code/libraries that saves you most memory. Load absolutely minimum of what you need to in memory. Eg: iterating on an array of 1 millions usernames in memory is more expensive than keeping them in database and paging over them.
2. **Error Handing:** There will be lots of them. API errors, unforeseen exceptions, memory leaks, network drops etc. Having robust error handling and recovery mechanism will save the day.
3. **Logging:** Good quality logging will be critical to keep a check on how different parts of system are doing. Look at [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston).
4. **Throttling API calls:**  Remember making 10,000 API calls at the same minute will likely crash your machine or even most APIs.At the very least go very slow due to memory overloads. However adding a slight delay (like 10 milliseconds) between every 10 parallel calls will be HUGE boost in speed and make the calls much more stable. This strategy is called **throttling** or **rate-limiting** the API calls. Finding a sweet spot that works for your problem is important. Yes going slow can actually make you reach goal faster!

Your question was quite broad without specific code question, this is a general strategy and hopefully will give you a good starting point and links to reference materials so you can start building your solution.

Comment: For # 4.  Yes I literally want to merge the results from each api and return that as my output.  I am using axios to make parallel api class, and doing a merge.  Instead  are you saying I should store each result in Redis, and then merge them?

Comment: For # 8, How do I make each copy of the same node program fetch a different set of inputs from the source database? After the results are merged, then I write to Redis.  

For # 9, Could you explain the optional post processing in Redis that is mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply.  Yes I am trying to create an API crawler, but confused about steps 4, 8, & 9.  Could you explain more?